# Passing JSON to WebApi in ASP.NET MVC 4 using .NET Framework 4.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5

I'm trying to pass model from Restful API. My code is:

```
public class RestApiInvocations<T>
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(string url, T model)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = null;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        try
        {
             result = client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, model).Result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        return result;

    }
}
```

In my API controller, I added the `FromUri` and `FromBody` attributes on the incoming parameters.

But my `HttpClient` object doesn't allow me to add a Content-Type header. I can add an Accept header, so I tried to add an accept header with application/json, but without result. Any suggestions? 
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private const string _Uri = "/ROUTE_TO_ACTION";

    public ReturnModel AddInvoice(SomeModel model)
    {
        var uri = string.Format(_Uri);
        var response = ServiceClient().PostAsJsonAsync(uri, model).Result;
        var result = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ReturnModel>().Result;
        return result;
    }

    private HttpClient ServiceClient()
    {
        var client= new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("YOUR_BASE_URL_TO_API");   //"http://localhost:8080/"
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3);
    }
```

Set your Urls/Endpoints and Run it.
And test you Api Endpoints on POSTMAN before writing the code.

Comment: Should I not be serializing the model and create an httpconent element out of that ?

Comment: client.PostAsJsonAsync(); will serialize your model to json. and response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ReturnModel>().Result with deserialize your response from API